# Export Moodle report in csv file

Tags: php, database, csv, report, moodle

Does anyone know any Moodle built in feature to export custom report into a csv file?

I've tried to find in documentation but there is nothing. There's this old [book](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/moodle-19-extension-development) which also have no practical information on exporting report into a csv file.

I've tried to dig into the source code and also in Moodle's administration block. You can export log reports as a csv file. So I'm sure there has to be something.

If anyone can help me with this that would be great help!

Thanks,
Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a plugin to do this, try one of these:

- https://moodle.org/plugins/view/report_customsql
- https://moodle.org/plugins/view/block_configurable_reports

If your're wanting to write code to do this, then take a look at lib/csvlib.class.php - that is a helpful wrapper for the standard PHP csv functions.

Comment: Thanks. That was help. Yea, I've already checked csvlib.class.php thinking that is a actually library that can be used someway. I hope one of the plugin is gonna work. Thanks.